# Multivariable Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, homology-cohomology

What's wrong with the following?

Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $f$ be smooth on $U$. Define $$F(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=\int_{0}^{x_1}f(t,x_2,\cdots,x_n)dt$$

Then $f$ has an 'antiderivative' since $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_1}=f$.

In more modern language, every closed form on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is exact, because $\mathbb{R}^n$ is contractible. But $U$ isn't necessarily contractible and so not every closed form on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is necessarily exact. If $f$ was chosen to be smooth on $\mathbb{R}^n$ instead of just $U$, would the above construction work? If so, why does it fail when we use $U$?

Comment: In your integral you seem to assume that if $(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in U$ then $(t,x_2,\dots,x_n)\in U$ for all $t\in [0;x_1]$. This is already some kind of convexity condition on $U$.